# Unable to connect to remote jupyter server using the vscode python plugin

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, remote-server, portforwarding

To connect to a remote jupyter server started with --no-browser option, I usually do  a local port forward and connect to the server using the web-browser. However, I would like to connect to that server using the vscode's python extension using its "Specify Jupyter server URI" option. At present, I tried passing the same url , something like http://127.0.01:8888/notebooks/some_nb.ipynb?token=asd45366778875434.adsdsgd35331, but nothing happens. 
How do I connect to this server form within vscode?Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey Kanchan. I'm one of the developers on this feature. I'll do what I can to help diagnose this issue for you. A couple of things to check quick. First off, the python extension is not doing any specific port forwarding here. So 127.0.0.1 is just going to resolve to your local machine, not the remote box. The second bit is that we don't support the .ipynb specific syntax that you were using to connect to a specific file on the server. I would try to just connect directly to the server. Finally I'm not sure but that "." in the token doesn't look expected, are you just using the autogen token?

Comment: When you start jupyter on the remote machine you should get a message like this:
[I 15:18:15.081 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 15:18:15.082 NotebookApp] http://(COMPUTERNAME or 127.0.0.1):8999/?token=6c5f85cfc27665ea5e6312936a14208e0180d1b6475acc98

From our tool you would connect with http://COMPUTERNAME:8999/?token=6c5f85cfc27665ea5e6312936a14208e0180d1b6475acc98

That's pretty much the only format that we support. The some_nb.ipynb isn't going to work.